# was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im having issues with this KVO-coding. In the code below I was first scanning for changes in key currentLocation, which was working fine but yet was calling getData twice, because, I presume, `CLLocation` has both `altitude` and `longitude` and hence changes twice. Okay, I thought I could neatly just scan either of those:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    dataManager = [[DataManager alloc]init];
    [dataManager addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentLocation.altitude”
         options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
}


-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
              change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
    //if(context==locationContext)
    location = [object valueForKeyPath:keyPath];

    //If scanning just currentLocation will get 2 events send....
     if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"currentLocation.altitude"]){
         if(location != nil){
            //connect and get data (if location changed more than WILL BE SPECIFIED
            [dataManager getData];
         }
     }
 }
```

But now I start getting following error msg, which I didn't see before:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x1742050d0 of class CLLocation was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it.

Answer (score 2):

When an observer is deallocated, the NSNotificationManager doesn't figure it out, and when it wants to send a message, it sends it to the deallocated observer - and then things go wrong.

You typically add code to your dealloc that unregisters your object from the notification manager.